# The inequality $2|6-x-2x^2|<x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Solve the inequality $$2|6-x-2x^2|<x$$
Let's see when $f(x)$ is equal to zero, $$-2x^2-x+6=0 \iff2x^2+x-6=0\\\Rightarrow x_{1,2}=-2;\dfrac32,$$ where $f(x)$ is the polynomial in the absolute value.

Now for $x\le-2$ our inequality becomes $$-2(6-x-2x^2)<x\\\iff x\in\left(\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{193}}{8};\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{193}}{8}\right)$$ For $-2\le x\le\dfrac32$ $$2(6-x-2x^2)<x\\-2(2x^2+x-6)<x\\x\in\left(-\infty;\dfrac{-3-\sqrt{201}}{8}\right)\cup\left(\dfrac{-3+\sqrt{201}}{8};+\infty\right)$$ We're done as the third case is the same as the first. So we should $\cup$ the intervals we got. Isn't the final answer $$x\in\left(-\infty;\dfrac{-3-\sqrt{201}}{8}\right)\cup\left(\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{193}}{8};+\infty\right)$$ What am I doing wrong? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%7C6-x-2x%5E2%7C%3Cx

Comment: It looks to me like you're forgetting to take into account the restrictions on $x$ brought about by the cases themselves. Note that you solution, under the assumption $-2 \le x \le \frac{3}{2}$, is unbounded, despite the fact that $x$ is assumed to belong to the bounded interval $[-2, 3/2]$ for example. So, not every point in your unbounded solution will satisfy the assumptions on $x$.

Comment: When $x$ is negative, there is no solution, since absolute value is non-negative

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting to constrain your “solution” intervals to be within your “case” intervals.

For example, when you write $x\in\left(\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{193}}{8};\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{193}}{8}\right) \approx (-1.86; 1.61)$, this is *incompatible* with your assumption that $x\le-2$, so this case doesn't contribute to the solution at all.